# How to unselect JButton from Space bar?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jbutton

Every time I start my program it runs the GUI window and one of the button is always selected. I'm not sure what this is called so I couldn't find any useful information on it. Right now when I start the program one of the button is selected so that if I pressed the "Space Bar" it'll *click* the button that is selected. I need to use the "Space Bar" as another keybinding command so I'd like to get rid of that pre-selection of the JButton. How would I do this? If I'm not being very clear maybe I can give some examples to help but I'm not sure what to show to make it clearer.

Basically I want the "Space Bar" to activate a keybinding command instead of activating the JButton that's selected.

Comment: Your problem is one of focus, in that the JButton gains focus on program start, and thus responds to space bar presses. One possible solution, kind of a kludge is to call `setFocusable(false)` on the JButton, but then possibly another JButton will gain focus.

Comment: **Edit**, please check out [trashgod's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12136312/522444) for a possible key bindings solution.

Comment: Thanks! Although probably not the best way to do it, I just setFocusable(false) to all the buttons.

Comment: Again please check the link to trashgod's answer for a better way.